# Find printer model name easily from IP list

Tags: printing, model, scrape

I have a list of about 3k enterprise printers. Printers can get moved, turned off, etc so there is a lot of movement.  The only way to really tell the model belonging to that IP is to go to the web address of the IP which has something similar to a control panel.

For example IP 10.10.10.1 is listed as a Dell 4000 in our records but when going to the IP its actually a HP LJ 3000.  The Dell was swapped out for whatever reason.

The control panels are formatted differently in regards to their html setup.  Some of the models are in the html title while some aren't.  Is there an easy methodology to develop to easily grab all of these from a list of about 3k?

Comment: You already have the full list of IPs ? Do you have a language of predilection ? Are you using *nix, Windows... ?

Comment: Yes I have the complete list of IPs and they are on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't really want to create your whole program, I will answer in broad terms.
I assume you have a fixed set of models, all of them have a control panel, and each of them have the same control panel (for instance, all the Dell 4000 have the same control panel).

- Create a list of control panel "known infos". For instance, let's say the Dell 4000 should have an element accessible by xpath `//table[id='title']/tr/th/`, and the HP LJ 3000 will have the name in the title.
- Create a program that loops on your list of IPs, get their control panel, and compare the infos located there until you find a match with the "known infos".